# Vuejs unscape sctring using two model binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in this simple `Html` tag which i used `vuejs` in background when in attach `website` into `input` element, that shown with escape string, i know i can use `v-html` but i should use `model` instead of that to have `unscape`

```html
<input v-model.trim="website" type="text" name="website"
```

`vuejs` code:

```js
export default {
    props: [
        'user'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            //
            website: userInfo.properties.website,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        //
    },
    methods: {
        
    }
};
```

can i use `filter` or `computed` or `underscorejs` library to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide an example of ``userInfo.properties.website``

Comment: @MajedBadawi yes sure, i have `http:\/\/www.site.com` in this `input` tag value and that should be `http:\\www.site.com`

Comment: You need to convert the initial value of the input or all the time?

Comment: @MajedBadawi yes that's right, in initial value on attaching into `input` tag

Comment: Why ``http:\\www.example.com`` and not ``http://www.example.com``?

Comment: @MajedBadawi i'm so sorry that was typo

Comment: Isn't it directly converted when the input is filled? Providing a fiddle or a demo would show the problem better.

Comment: What encoding (or method) are you using that escapes the slashes? Can't you just unescape that value in `data()`?